# subdomain for static page in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails 3 app that needs to have subdomains that point to a static page in my code base

EXAMPLE:

**mk1.mysite.com** needs to show the page that is located

**app > views > about > page.html.haml**

That page sits at **mysite.com/about/page.html**

QUESTION:

How can I configure the routes to display the subdirectory (**mysite.com/about/page.html**) page by visiting the subdomain (**mk1.mysite.com**)?

I have this in my routes.rb

```
match '/' => 'about/page.html', :constraints => { :subdomain => 'mk1' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is your regular root route located in your routes file? Is it located before or after the line you listed in your post?

So if you have a line like

```
root :to => "foo#index"
```

In your routes file, above

```
match '/' => 'about/page.html', :constraints => { :subdomain => 'mk1' }
```

The root route would be called first and your subdomain route won't be called.